# What's the difference between "would do" and "would have done"?

Tags: grammar, difference

- If I'd go to the party last night *I would be tired now*.
- If I'd go to the party last night *I would have met lots of people*.

What's the difference?

Comment: "If I'd gone to the party"   The meaning here is "If I had gone",   and not "If I would go" so the verb should be in its past participle form "gone".

Comment: The difference is just that If I'd gone to the party last night *...I would **be tired now*** AND/OR *...I would **have met** lots of people **then***.

Answer (score 6):

They both present a counterfactual situation "If I had gone to the party". You can infer that the speaker did not go to the party.

The difference in conclusion is therefore a matter of tense - "I would be tired now"  is speaking of the present time  (an apparently past tense form of the verb is used, this is the result of backshifting)  "I would have met lots of people" is speaking of the past (again, backshifted to past perfect)

Since these are counterfactual you may infer that the speaker is not tired now (in the first example) and did not meet lots of people (in the second) Note that when written out like that, the present and past tense indicate clearly that the first is about the present time, but the second is about a past time.